# yii2 saveAs two files, saves only one

Tags: file-upload, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i dont know why, but i have form where i specify two uploads (preview, detail) and when im trying to save them, detail is saved but preview not. Db has results as i expect - saved $slug in column imageSrc and imageDetailSrc

```
const UPLOAD_FILE_URL = 'uploads/recipes/';
const UPLOAD_FILE_DETAILS_URL = self::UPLOAD_FILE_URL.'details/';    

$filePath = self::UPLOAD_FILE_URL . $slug . '.' . $this->imageSrc->extension;
            $filePathDetail = self::UPLOAD_FILE_DETAILS_URL . $slug . '.' . $this->imageDetailSrc->extension;

            if ($this->imageSrc->saveAs($filePath) && $this->imageDetailSrc->saveAs($filePathDetail)) {
                $this->imageSrc = $slug . '.' . $this->imageSrc->extension;
                $this->imageDetailSrc = $slug . '.' . $this->imageDetailSrc->extension;
            }

            if ($this->save(false, ['imageSrc', 'imageDetailSrc'])) {
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii2 official documentation states that saveAs function uses move_uploaded_file() function to move the temporary file. Hence the temporary file gets deleted when you call saveAs function for the first time. If you do not want saveAs to delete then you should do send false as the second parameter to your saveAs function.

```
const UPLOAD_FILE_URL = 'uploads/recipes/';
const UPLOAD_FILE_DETAILS_URL = self::UPLOAD_FILE_URL.'details/';    

$filePath = self::UPLOAD_FILE_URL . $slug . '.' . $this->imageSrc-
>extension;
$filePathDetail = self::UPLOAD_FILE_DETAILS_URL . $slug . '.' . $this->imageDetailSrc->extension;

if ($this->imageSrc->saveAs($filePath, false) && $this->imageDetailSrc->saveAs($filePathDetail)) {
      $this->imageSrc = $slug . '.' . $this->imageSrc->extension;
      $this->imageDetailSrc = $slug . '.' . $this->imageDetailSrc->extension;
}
if ($this->save(false, ['imageSrc', 'imageDetailSrc'])) {
   return true;
}
```